# How to set up Kubenetes not mark the pod as running while not all containers ready

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

This is probably a basic question: when I use `kubectl rollout start deployment ...` to roll start my pods, I find the POD is marked as `Running` state while there are still more containers not up yet.

If I understand correctly, once a POD is marked `Running`, it will start serving the traffic, right? In fact, the POD is not ready since waiting for more containers to be up.

How do I prevent Kube from marking it as `Running` until all containers are running?

Thanks!

[image: one example]

Comment: Don't mix up container and pods. Here it's replicas of a pod (and pod can contain several containers). And you rollout a replicaSet. Anyway, K8S is designed to avoid downtime and therefore create new pod (surge value) before terminating the old one (with maxUnavailable value). I don't know if you can accept a downtime or not. If so, you can recreate your deployment. It's brutal, but it works! Else, you can perform a A/B (or canary) deployment, and switch to the old to the new one in one shot. You can find a lot of documentation on those options.

Comment: Thanks, for the simplicity. I would like to group all 5 services (containers) into one pod and scale by # of pods.

Comment: It's simpler but you won't scale great. You will scale service that are not required. Maybe OK at the beginning, but keep that in your backlog!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes pods will not receive traffic until all of their containers are ready. You can configure a probe to check whether each container is ready via container readiness probes.

If no readiness probe is configured for a container, it will be marked as ready to receive traffic once it has started running. This is not ideal for most servers or databases.

Below is a sample readiness probe that queries port 80 through HTTP. More info in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#http-probes).

```yaml
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    port: 80
    path: /
  initialDelaySeconds: 5
  periodSeconds: 5
  failureThreshold: 5
```

- `initialDelaySeconds` indicates a delay after which the probe will start to run.
- `periodSeconds` sets the period to wait between each readiness check
- `failureThreshold` the number of probe failures that can be tolerated. After `failureThreshold` failures, the container will be marked as not ready. Initially, the container will be marked as not ready as well.

Note: Readiness and liveness probes run consistently for the whole lifespan of a container. They are meant to be lightweight, meaning that they won't take up considerable resources.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer - I think I have already set this up. 

This does not seem to answer my question, the reason is that I do not know why the POD is marked as a RUNNING state even, though the number of containers in ready is 3 out of 5 as you can see fro the screenshot I attached.

Comment: So the question is about how to prevent the POD to marked as RUNNING while containers are still bootstrapping, not about how to ensure each container is ready

Comment: What you're referring to is the pod's phase. From the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-phase), a pod will be marked as Ready when "The Pod has been bound to a node, and all of the containers have been created. At least one container is still running, or is in the process of starting or restarting."

Comment: The fact that the pod is in Running phase only means that at least one container is up and running, however, until the corresponding readiness probe passes, no endpoints will be created for that pod on the container's port, meaning that the container itself will not receive traffic until it's ready.

Comment: From what I can see with your setup, you could break down your pods into different deployments, which is the best approach when it comes to Kubernetes. You can also shoot your shot with [custom readiness conditions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-readiness-status), although I would recommend you break down your Deployment into multiple ones, as that is the Kubernetes way.

Comment: And I'm not just saying this - It's easier to enforce pod readiness with single-container pods. AFAIK Kubernetes does not have a way of preventing traffic from being routed into a container if another container in the same pod is not ready. The virtual network endpoint will not get created until the container on that port is ready, however, if you don't implement programmatic logic to ensure each container's dependencies are live before them, readiness probes will not be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `livenessProbe`,`readinessProbe` and `startupProbe` for each container to change to ready state only if all containers are healthy

```
 readinessProbe:
  tcpSocket:
    port: 8080
  initialDelaySeconds: 5
  periodSeconds: 10
livenessProbe:
  tcpSocket:
    port: 8080
  initialDelaySeconds: 15
  periodSeconds: 20
```

you can find more detailed documentation in https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-readiness-probes